# parent class call static child method

Tags: java

im trying to create a extendable class that can have some methods like: `createInstanceFromArgument(Class<T> class)` and other methods:

the Abstractclass that will be extended from others models:

```
public class AbstractModelsMethods {



    private DocumentRevision documentRevision;
    public DocumentRevision getDocumentRevision() {
        return documentRevision;
    }

    public void setDocumentRevision(DocumentRevision documentRevision) {
        this.documentRevision = documentRevision;
    }

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        T object = GsonUtils.getGson().fromJson(json, (Type) classOfT);
        return Primitives.wrap(classOfT).cast(object);
    }

    public static <T> T fromRevision(DocumentRevision revision, Class<T> classOfT) throws JsonSyntaxException {
        T object = fromJson(revision.getBody().toString(), classOfT);
        try {
            Method m = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDocumentRevision", classOfT);
            m.invoke(revision);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Primitives.wrap(classOfT).cast(object);
    }
}
```

and a sample model class

```
public class MyPersonModel extends AbstractModelsMethods {


    String oid;
    String name;

//   other fields and boilerplate not related to Abstractclass


}
```

when i try to call:   `MyPersonModel person = MyPersonModel.fromRevision(revision);`

it populate the fields at the MypersonModel, but the method inside Abstract is not caled and when i try to print it:

```
Log.d("Testing", "PERSON REVISION: " + person.getDocumentRevision().toString());
```

its crash saying:

```
Caused 

by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

so of course this:

```
   Method m = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDocumentRevision", classOfT);
        m.invoke(revision);
```

is not called

maybe im trying to make magic?

suma: i want all models can instantiate all others (of course its depend about the second parameter, the Class, so it will return a instance of this class, and i dont pretend to use `Person.fromRevision(revision, Dog.class)` the must importante thing here is that i need to pass a revision that has a json that can be anything and save the Revision inside the same obj that it created and returned to me

possible?

Comment: This approach violates some basic tenets of object-oriented programming. For one, parent classes should have no concept of their subtypes. For another, you are using reflection to imitate polymorphism, instead of just using polymorphism. You have no type model. Why do you not simply override the `setDocumentRevision` method in your subclass and let the automatic inheritance mechanism do the job for you, instead of using messy reflection techniques?

Comment: @LewBloch so i should stop using T <T> and use the real class?!

Comment: It's a complex topic that I can't answer in a comment. We're talking about the basics of object-oriented programming. I don't know WTF you're doing with the generics; it makes no sense to me. I'm saying that instead of reflectively calling `setDocumentRevision` that you follow a pattern similar to `AbstractModelsMethods model = new MyPersonModel(); model.setDocumentRevision(revision);`.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve. "*i want all models can instantiate*" what are models? Why not write an example that we can run and see what the problem is, and you should write what you want to happen in respect to the code.